# How to pay users' withdrawal amounts through paypal using their details in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have a number of PayPal user accounts, and I wish to use those accounts to pay those users' withdrawal amounts through PayPal.

I have multiple user details. I have their paypal details, too.

By just using their paypal id, I want to transfer them their withdrawal amount.

Right now I have integrated PayPal in my Laravel application. But, their first step is "Checkout".
I just want to enter their paypal ID and send their withdrawal amount.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Install the PayPal SDK:

Install the PayPal SDK in your Laravel project using Composer: composer require paypal/rest-api-sdk-php.
Configure PayPal settings:

Add your PayPal credentials to the .env file of your Laravel project:

```
PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID=your_paypal_client_id
PAYPAL_SECRET=your_paypal_secret
```

You can obtain the client ID and secret by creating a PayPal developer account and creating an application in the dashboard.

Create a Payout Service:
Generate a new service in Laravel using the following command: 'php artisan make:service PayoutService'.
Implement Payout functionality:
Open the app/Services/PayoutService.php file and update it with the following code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Services;

use PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential;
use PayPal\Rest\ApiContext;
use PayPal\Api\Payout;
use PayPal\Api\PayoutSenderBatchHeader;
use PayPal\Api\Currency;

class PayoutService
{
    protected $apiContext;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->apiContext = new ApiContext(
            new OAuthTokenCredential(
                config('paypal.client_id'),
                config('paypal.secret')
            )
        );
    }

    public function payout($paypalEmail, $amount, $currency = 'USD')
    {
        $payouts = new Payout();

        $senderBatchHeader = new PayoutSenderBatchHeader();

        $senderBatchHeader->setSenderBatchId(uniqid())
            ->setEmailSubject('Withdrawal Amount')
            ->setRecipientType('Email');

        $item = new Currency();
        $item->setValue($amount)->setCurrency($currency);

        $payouts->setSenderBatchHeader($senderBatchHeader)
            ->addItem($item)
            ->setRecipientType('Email')
            ->setEmailSubject('Withdrawal Amount')
            ->setItems([
                [
                    'recipient_type' => 'EMAIL',
                    'amount' => [
                        'value' => $amount,
                        'currency' => $currency
                    ],
                    'receiver' => $paypalEmail,
                    'note' => 'Withdrawal Amount'
                ]
            ]);

        $payout = $payouts->create(null, $this->apiContext);

        return $payout;
    }

}
```

This code initializes the ApiContext with your PayPal credentials. The payout method creates a new payout object to send money to the specified PayPal email address with the defined amount.

Use the Payout Service:
In your controller or wherever you want to initiate the payout, import the PayoutService:

```
use App\Services\PayoutService;
```

Inject the PayoutService in your controller's method:

```
public function payWithdrawal(PayoutService $payoutService)
{
    $paypalEmail = 'recipient_email@example.com';
    $amount = '10.00'; // withdrawal amount
    $currency = 'USD';

    $payout = $payoutService->payout($paypalEmail, $amount, $currency);

    // Handle the payout response
    // You can check $payout->getBatchHeader()->getBatchStatus() to verify if the payout was successful
    // You can also obtain the payout details using $payout->getLinks()

    return response()->json(['message' => 'Payout initiated'], 200);
}
```

Provide the PayPal email address of the user and the withdrawal amount to the payout method in your controller. You can then handle the payout response accordingly.

Routes and Views:
Create a route to handle the payout initiation by adding the following to your routes file (routes/web.php or routes/api.php):

```
use App\Http\Controllers\PaymentController;
Route::post('/payout', [PaymentController::class, 'payWithdrawal']);
```

You can create a form in your view to gather the withdrawal amount and PayPal email address. On submitting the form, make a POST request to the /payout endpoint. Make sure to handle any exceptions or errors that might occur during the process for a better user experience.

Comment: payout via payment transaction id how to get?